# How can I run unittests in Dart Editor?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-editor

I have the web application project in Dart Editor and I want to write some unittests for it. I tried to create .dart file with a simple unit test in the same project (with main function etc) but in context menu I had only 'run as javascript' and 'run in dartium' options (when I click any of them nothing happens). How can I run unittest as console app from Dart Editor? What is the most convenient way of doing such tests?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem. I wanted to unit test the behaviour of my widgets (from the dart editor v1.3.3) having mocked out the UI elements, but found that, because I was importing *dart:html*, I was forced to run the tests as if they were a web app with one of the *'Run in browser'* menu options.

It seems that as soon as you import *dart:html* or a package that does so you're stuck with the *'Run in browser'* options for your unit tests (creating another package to test the original one doesn't solve the problem either, for the same reason, it has to import the *dart:html* one). And yes, attempting to run regular unit tests with the *'Run in browser'* options just fails silently and does absolutely nothing.

The **simple solution** is to use an html file to run your tests. You can adapt your unit tests to output to the webpage if you like but it's not essential.

**test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Unit Test Results</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**test.dart**

```dart
// Used to illustrate the problem. Importing dart:html causes
// the context menu to show only the 'Run in browser' options.
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

// Required if you want to use useHtmlConfiguration().
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';

void main() {
    // Required if you want to output the unit test results
    // to the HTML page rather than the console.
    useHtmlConfiguration();

    test ('simple test', () => expect(true, isTrue, reason:"true isn't true"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually had the exact same problem as described in the question. After some searching I discovered my directory structure was incorrect.

my directory structure was as follows:

```
/projectname
  /web
    index.html
    main.dart
    /test
      test_file.dart
```

This is **wrong**. I changed my directory structure to the following:

```
/projectname
  /web
    index.html
    main.dart
  /test
    test_file.dart
```

As you can see, i moved the `/test` directory out of the `/web` directory. As soon as I did this, I was now able to right click the `test_file.dart` file and select 'run' in the context menu (**not** 'run as javascript' or 'run in dartium') and see the tests being run in the built-in console in the dart editor.

For more information: the full pub package layout conventions can be found here: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html

information about unit tests in dart can be found here: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#configuring-the-test-environment (including configuring the test environment for stuff like html output etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a web application project so you want test code that runs in the browser?
I have never experienced that I have `run as javascript` or `run in Dartium` for console applications. Did you import 'dart:html' in this dart file?

Anyways maybe this answers your question:

You can run unittests testing web code with `content_shell`.
The Dart installation directory contains a script to download `content_shell` (it is not part of the Dart installation package to keep it small).

You actually run an HTML page:

```bash
content_shell --dump-render-tree polymer_ajax.html
```

I haven't tried but when you build your test code to JavaScript using

```
pub build test
```

you should be able to run the result using `content_shell`.
DartEditor doesn't show a run option for a bash script (just tried) so you would need to build a Dart script that invodes `content_shell`.

The Dart team has mentioned several times recently that they want to improve the test story but the infrastructure for run/build is still work in progress. When this has settled I guess the test support will be worked on next.

Comment: I didn't import dart:html but I imported library (test target) that imports dart:html. It was just my blind guess how it can be done. I will try `content_shell`. Anyway, nice to hear that testing is important for dart team.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will describe solution that works best for me. 
I created separate project for tests in Dart Editor (polymer web application - the same as target project). Main `.html` file in test project imports `.dart` file that looks like:

```
library foo_test;
import '../../foo_project/web/foo.dart'; //test target
import '../packages/mock/mock.dart';
import '../packages/unittest/unittest.dart';
import '../packages/unittest/html_config.dart';

void main() {
    useHtmlConfiguration();

    test("sample test", () {
        expect(foo_function(), equals(expected_result) );
    });
}
```

`useHtmlConfiguration()` creates some nice page with all tests listed. I also tried `useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration()` as described in https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/ but it doesn't print stack traces (neither in page nor in console) so it is rather useless for me. There is also `useHtmlInteractiveConfiguration()` in documentation but it doesn't exist in `unittest` package.